# How to fill values in new column in dataframe on a multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am  trying to fill column **Final** with values if **Number** contains some values and **Code** contains `0` then the value present in **Code** i.e `0` should be replaced by the value of the **Number** column, which I am able to do with:

```
df['Final'] = np.where(df['Code'] == 0, df['Number'], df['Code'])
```

but for rows no. 5, 6 and 7 I am facing a problem, the value should be in the **Final** column with least filled `00` values. How can this be achieved with pandas? The double zero (`00`) can come in consecutive manner only.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: your code works perfectly for me

Comment: Final column should contain column value from number and code which has  least filled 00 values.

Comment: What is the type of your `Code` and `Number` column? Can you check `df.dtypes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare values with [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) and chain 3 conditions with `|` for `bitwise OR` and `&` for `bitwise AND` with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
print (df)
   No    Number      Code     Final
0   1  78797071         0  78797071
1   2         0  89797071  89797071
2   3         0  57797074  57797074
3   4  39797571         0  39797571
4   5  62170000  62175268  62175268
5   6  52130000  52000000  52130000
6   7  52146700  52140000  52146700

a = df['Number'].astype(str).str.count('0')
b = df['Code'].astype(str).str.count('0')

#test if value is not 0
m1 = df['Code'] != 0
#test if value is 0
m2 = df['Number'] == 0
#test if number of 0 is higher
m3 = a > b

df['Final'] = np.where((m1 & m2) | m3, df['Code'], df['Number'])
print (df)

   No    Number      Code     Final
0   1  78797071         0  78797071
1   2         0  89797071  89797071
2   3         0  57797074  57797074
3   4  39797571         0  39797571
4   5  62170000  62175268  62175268
5   6  52130000  52000000  52130000
6   7  52146700  52140000  52146700
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.assign(m1 = m1,
                 m2 = m2,
                 m3 = m3,
                 m1ANDm2 = m1 & m2,
                 mask= (m1 & m2) | m3))

   No    Number      Code     Final     m1     m2     m3  m1ANDm2   mask
0   1  78797071         0  78797071  False  False  False    False  False
1   2         0  89797071  89797071   True   True  False     True   True
2   3         0  57797074  57797074   True   True  False     True   True
3   4  39797571         0  39797571  False  False  False    False  False
4   5  62170000  62175268  62175268   True  False   True    False   True
5   6  52130000  52000000  52130000   True  False  False    False  False
6   7  52146700  52140000  52146700   True  False  False    False  False
```

Comment: you have't noticed the case 5,6 and 7 i am facing problem with that

Comment: @ParthTiwari - can you check now?

Comment: it throws error when i write the first two lines i.e. a and b( invalid literal for int() with base 10: '')

Comment: @ParthTiwari - Are missing values in `Number` ? Or only strings with `''` for missing values?

Comment: @ParthTiwari - Answer was changed

Comment: It working thanks a lot its working could explain 
df['Final'] = np.where((m2 | m3) & m1, df['Code'], df['Number'])

Comment: hey @jezrael could you explain why we have used (m2 | m3) & m1 i am getting confused over this

Comment: i basically want to know how did you applied the logic over (m2 | m3) & m1

Comment: @Parth Tiwary I check it again and need to change to `mask = (m1 & m2) | m3` it means m1 and m2 with bitwise AND and then OR with m3. I am now offline, on phone only, so not tested, but I hope working nice

Answer (score 1):

We can `count` the amount of zero's in both columns and take that with us in `np.where`:

```
count1 = df['Number'].astype(str).str.count('0') 
count2 = df['Code'].replace(0, np.NaN).astype(str).str.count('0')

df['Final'] = np.where(df['Code']==0 | (count1<count2), df['Number'], df['Code'])
```

**Output**

```
   No    Number      Code     Final
0   1  78797071         0  78797071
1   2         0  89797071  89797071
2   3         0  57797074  57797074
3   4  39797571         0  39797571
4   5  62170000  62175268  62175268
5   6  52130000  52000000  52000000
6   7  52146700  52140000  52140000
```